# No routes match location in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am migrating to `react-router-dom` v6. I have nested route in a component and in v5, it works fine. But now it not working as it always saying no routes matched location.
I want to put route in my `Layout` component and then when component is hit, it will call route inside. It is not working. I used to use `Switch` and `BrowserRouter` in v5 and everything is good. I can not figure out what is wrong.

Here are my code:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import RootRouters from "./components/routers/RootRouters";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <RootRouters />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

RootRouters:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "../auth-page/login";
import Home from "../home/home";
import SignUp from "../auth-page/sign-up";
import AdminLogin from "../../pages/admin/Login";
import Layout from "../../components/admin/layout/Layout";

const RootRouters = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            {/* <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> */}
            <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/admin/login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
            <Route element={<Layout />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default RootRouters;
```

Layout:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./layout.css";
import Sidebar from "../sidebar/Sidebar";
import TopNav from "../topnav/TopNav";
import AdminRoutes from "../../routers/AdminRouters";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import ThemeAction from "../../../redux/actions/ThemeAction";

const Layout = () => {
    const themeReducer = useSelector((state) => state.ThemeReducer);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        const themeClass = localStorage.getItem("themeMode", "theme-mode-light");

        const colorClass = localStorage.getItem("colorMode", "theme-mode-light");

        dispatch(ThemeAction.setMode(themeClass));

        dispatch(ThemeAction.setColor(colorClass));
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <Route
            render={(props) => (
                <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode} ${themeReducer.color}`}>
                    <Sidebar {...props} />
                    <div className="layout__content">
                        <TopNav />
                        <div className="layout__content-main">
                            <AdminRoutes />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        />
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

AdminRoutes:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "../../pages/admin/Dashboard";
import Customers from "../../pages/admin/Customers";
import Products from "../../pages/admin/Products";
import NewDocument from "../../pages/admin/document/NewDocument";
import DetailDocument from "../../pages/admin/document/DetailDocument";
import EditDocument from "../../pages/admin/document/EditDocument";

const AdminRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Route>
            <Route path="/admin/documents/new" component={NewDocument} />
            <Route path="/admin/documents/detail" component={DetailDocument} />
            <Route path="/admin/documents/update" component={EditDocument} />
            <Route path="/admin/customers" component={Customers} />
            <Route path="/admin/products" component={Products} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
        </Route>
    );
};

export default AdminRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `RootRouter` to render the `Layout` component on a `path="*"` so it can be involved with route matching, e.g. that it has a path.

```
const RootRouters = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      {/* <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> */}
      <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/admin/login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Layout />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Update `Layout` to render the UI directly, `Route` components no longer have render function props.

```
const Layout = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode} ${themeReducer.color}`}>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="layout__content">
        <TopNav />
        <div className="layout__content-main">
          <AdminRoutes />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Update `AdminRoutes` to use the React-Router v6 APIs/syntax, namely rendering the `Route` components into a `Routes` component, and using the `element` prop and passing JSX.

```
const AdminRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin/documents/new" element={<NewDocument />} />
      <Route path="/admin/documents/detail" element={<DetailDocument />} />
      <Route path="/admin/documents/update" element={<EditDocument />} />
      <Route path="/admin/customers" element={<Customers />} />
      <Route path="/admin/products" element={<Products />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  );
};
```

### Alternative suggestion

If you would prefer to use nested routes you could update the following.

Update the `Layout` component to render an `Outlet` component instead of the `AdminRoutes`.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div className={`layout ${themeReducer.mode} ${themeReducer.color}`}>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="layout__content">
        <TopNav />
        <div className="layout__content-main">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Render the "admin routes" directly in `RootRouters`.

```
const RootRouters = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      {/* <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> */}
      <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/admin">
        <Route path="login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="documents/new" element={<NewDocument />} />
          <Route path="documents/detail" element={<DetailDocument />} />
          <Route path="documents/update" element={<EditDocument />} />
          <Route path="customers" element={<Customers />} />
          <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry for reply too late and many thanks for your supporting. But my **SideBar** component needs properties from parent to display so it throws me error **Cannot read properties of undefined**. Can you help me with this? @drew-reese

Comment: I've fixed it by using useLocation. So grateful for your help.